# C# Entity Framework load dynamically view into the context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dynamic, reflection

I have a foreach which will call severel views, and i try to laod this views dynamically into the dbContext of entity framework.

What I have so fare is :

```
var context = new DbContext();
var type = Type.GetType($"XXX.XXXXXXX.XXXX.XXXXX.{exportItem.DataSourceView}, XXX.XXXXXXX.XXXX.XXXXX");
context.Set(type).Load();
var result = context.Set(type).AsQueryable().Cast<View_DataLoad>().ToList();
```

This works so far, but I have to Cast the result to the class which I set to the dbContext.

How can I add dynamically class to the cast function?

Or is there a better way to load dynamically query's to the entity framework?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly - you want to query the whole view as data source ? You can write simple SQL query and it will be instantiated as your Type using this method:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(string sql);
```